# Why move from an rvalue?

Tags: c++, move, rvalue, lvalue

I can't understand why would we move a promise object in line

```
std::thread t1(Findeven,std::move(evenSum),a,b);
```

Effort put:
I learnt about move semantics and rvlaues and lvalues, but still this part is unclear.

I was expecting data to be moved from an rvalue, not to an rvalue.
I know that inside the function rvalue ref will just act as an lvalue, but still that doesn't clear the confusion.
Also isn't moving risky here as that would make evenSum an rvalue, meaning it can be destroyed "pretty soon", and if it points to the data contained in shared state, the data would also be destroyed rendering it unavailable for use for FutureSum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future> 
typedef long int ull;
using namespace std;

void Findeven(std::promise<ull>&& evenSumPromise,ull start, ull end) {
    ull even = 0;
    for(ull i = start ; i <= end ; i++) {
        if(i%2 == 0) {
            even++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    
    evenSumPromise.set_value(even);
}

int main() {
    ull a = 0;
    ull b = 190000;
    std::promise<ull> evenSum;
    std::future<ull> FutureSum = evenSum.get_future();
    std::thread t1(Findeven,std::move(evenSum),a,b);
    t1.join();
    cout << FutureSum.get();
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of texts.

Comment: ok ill change it

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to take a broader look instead of taking a deeper look at details. [4) promise is not copyable.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/promise)

Comment: promise and future can be imagined as two sides of a pipe through which the to be computed value flows. Neither of them can be copied, because the pipe has only 1 input and 1 output.

Comment: To be clear: `OddSum` is not an rvalue, so the title of the question is misleading.

Comment: Another common source of confusion is that the `thread` constructor doesn't convert types to match the function object; the call `std::thread t1(... OddSum ...)` passes `OddSum` by value, even though the function object takes it as a `&&`. It creates an `OddSum` object in the new thread, and passes that object to your thread function; that's where the conversion takes place.

Comment: Some side notes: (1) [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), (2) It's also not a good practice to use `typedef long int ull;`.

Comment: @saket -- probably. Some folks on SO shoot first and think later. If they think at all.

Comment: @PeteBecker Can you suggest some good resource to learn threading in c++, I am quite new to coding and all

Comment: @saket "I can't understand why would we move a promise object in line" - what else would you do?  As already pointed out, you can't copy the promise.  Was that the source of your confusion?

Comment: @wearetherobots , yes , but then I tried doing something like `void Findeven(std::promise<ull>& evenSumPromise......)` , that also doesn't work, why is that ?

Comment: @saket -- if you're quite new to coding you're not ready for multi-threaded code. You need a solid foundation before you deal with the complexities that threads introduce.

Comment: @PeteBecker So what should I do? I learnt about classes and stuff , then about move semantics , How do I get "ready"? I am sorry if this came off as rude.

Comment: @saket -- that didn't come off as rude.

Comment: also @PeteBecker Doesn't OddSum (now evenSum) become an rvalue in main after we call std::move(OddSum) ?

Comment: @saket -- no; `std::move` doesn't change the object at all. It says "pass this object as an rvalue reference", nothing more. It's still a named object, so it's not an rvalue. If you call a function that takes an object by value, moving that object in the call to the function will use the move constructor rather than the copy constructor. The state of the original object depends on what the move constructor does.